# Deleting __MigrationHistory Table From Database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I want to know what will happen if I delete `__MigrationHistory` table from working database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my issue I decided to delete this table, Nothing happened application starts and throws an `Exception` for each `Entity` about `Entity` already exists in database.So don't try to delete this table if you already deployed your Application.